# Modify Existing Code that Lists Folders/Sub-Folders to Include File Names

Tags: vba, excel, directory

I have a code that will completely list the entirety of all of the folders and sub-folders within a given path. I foolishly ran the code on a folder containing tens of thousands of sub-folders, so while I wait for that to finish I would like to start thinking about the next step.

I need the code to also go one step deeper into the rabbit hole and pick up file names. Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit 

    Dim i As Long, j As Long 
    Dim searchfolders As Variant 
    Dim FileSystemObject 

    Sub ListOfFolders() 
        Dim LookInTheFolder As String 

        i = 1 
        LookInTheFolder = "C:\" ' As you know; you should modificate this row.
        Set FileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
        For Each searchfolders In FileSystemObject.GetFolder(LookInTheFolder).SubFolders 
            Cells(i, 1) = searchfolders 
            i = i + 1 
            SearchWithin searchfolders 
        Next searchfolders 

    End Sub 

Sub SearchWithin(searchfolders) 
        On Error GoTo exits 
    For Each searchfolders In FileSystemObject.GetFolder(searchfolders).SubFolders 
        j = UBound(Split(searchfolders, "\")) 
        Cells(i, j) = searchfolders 
        i = i + 1 
        SearchWithin searchfolders 
        Next searchfolders 
        exits: 
End Sub
```

The code outputts into a tree like chart and I would like to extend to the last branch including file names.

Please help! 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had to do this many times, and many times over I've used this same function.

```
Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
' Returns the rightmost characters of a string upto but not including the rightmost '\'

    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Just pass the entire path of the file into the function. And it will return the file name.

Another option is this function.

```
Public Function RecursiveDir(colFiles As Collection, _
                          ByVal strFolder As String, _
                          strFileSpec As String, _
                          bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

 Dim strTemp As String
 Dim colFolders As New Collection
 Dim vFolderName As Variant

'Add files in strFolder matching strFileSpec to colFiles
 strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
 strTemp = Dir(strFolder & strFileSpec)
 Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
     colFiles.Add strFolder & strTemp
     strTemp = Dir
 Loop

'Fill colFolders with list of subdirectories of strFolder
 If bIncludeSubfolders Then
     strTemp = Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)
     Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
         If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then
             If (GetAttr(strFolder & strTemp) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                 colFolders.Add strTemp
             End If
         End If
         strTemp = Dir
     Loop

'Call RecursiveDir for each subfolder in colFolders
     For Each vFolderName In colFolders
         Call RecursiveDir(colFiles, strFolder & vFolderName, strFileSpec, True)
     Next vFolderName
 End If

'Garbage collection
 Set colFolders = Nothing

End Function
```

This function will populate a collection of every file name in a given directory. And if you want you can set the `bIncludeSubfolders` to true, and it will recursively search all subfolders within this directory. To use this function, you need the following:

```
Dim colFiles As New Collection ' The collection of files
Dim Path As String ' The parent Directory you want to search
Dim subFold As Boolean ' Search sub folders, yes or no?
Dim FileExt As String ' File extension type to search for
```

Then just set `FileExt = "*.*"` Which will find every file with every file extension. Hopefully this helps a little more.

Comment: Im not quite sure how to implement. Will review and try

Comment: I will edit my post and give you some different code. I found another way that ive done file searching.